# net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED when using Rack::Deflater on jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, jruby, rack, deflate

`net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`
I am receiving this in chrome when Rack::Deflater is enabled, when using on jruby.
After having some reading it looks like this is some jruby issue with gzipping.

Is there any alternative for serving gzipped assets? And also dynamically gzipping responses?

I am hosting the application on heroku. Rails version is 3.2.X

I think this is related with this issue:
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1371#ref-issue-15218894

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope. We haven't fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

This error comes by browser

The response should contain the header telling the client which compression scheme is being used: Content-Encoding: gzip and 
The request should contain the correct header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"